# How to set JInternalFrame minimised title background?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I can set the title bar background when maximised using InternalFrame.activeTitleBackground and InternalFrame.inactiveTitleBackground but how do I set it when the internal frame is minimised?

Comment: Post some code to make it easier for us to follow. I'm not sure what you mean. You want to change the background-color of an InternalFrame, when it's minimized?

Comment: background color of an InternalFrame's title bar, when it's minimised.  Setting the above lnf properties will change the color when it's maximised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy solution. The frame colors are part of the UI, so you will need to create a custom UI to do what you want. You can start by searching the Java source code to see where the "activeTitleBackground" and "inactiveTitleBackground" properties are used. That will give you an idea of the class and method that needs to be customized.